# Trying to save multiple input data separated by a delimiter into singular records in database

Tags: ms-access, input, textbox, delimiter, inventory

I am currently trying to create an inventory database for my company. The issue is that inputting data one item at a time is inefficient. Thus, we bought a scanner. The scanner can hold multiple items in its memory, and when transferred to a location (textbox, Excel cell), all the data is input in that one cell separated by a tab delimiter.

Is there a way (`split()` function maybe) where I can essentially "paste" all the memory from the scanner into a single textbox on a form (so that a textbox has "data1 data2 data3 data4" and then save it such that my table now contains the data in separate records?

record1 - data1
record2 - data2
record3 - data3

I'm  just learning Access so the syntax understanding is generally where I struggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having read all the data into your text box, you need a button to click, with the OnClick event code looking something like this:

```
Dim astrInput() As String
Dim i As Integer

astrInput = Split(txtData, " ")
For i = 0 To UBound(astrInput)
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO myTable(DataColumn) VALUES ('" & astrInput(i) & "')"
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you for responding!

I will work on implementing this and come back if I have any issues if you don't mind

Comment: Would this button for the OnClick event code be able to be coupled with the simple save button? I'm thinking, add the button for saving a record, change the macro to actual VBA code, and then implement the above code you've suggested? I mean to distinguish between the VBA code for saving a record of a text box as being separate from the above code, or would this replace that code? If that makes sense

Comment: IT WORKED! YOU'RE  A LIFESAVER! 

hahahah thank you very much for the help @Skippy, would've taken ages to figure the out on my own!